# Appeding not working, list shows just 1 item in Python with Geopy (cities)

Tags: python, append, geopy

I created a code to create a list from GEOPY.

It iterates thru a Excel file (Column with all Latitudes/Longitudes)

as the API provides different names for the Raw, I insert all possibilities with Try/Except.

Everything looks good but the result is just one item in the list, supposed to be 5 as my test list contains 5 rows..

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

arquivo = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\nando\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\LatLon.xlsx')

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="geoapi", timeout=10)

listacidades= []

for index, row in arquivo.iterrows():
  coord = str(row['Concatenado'])

Location = geolocator.reverse(coord, language="en")

#print(Location.raw["address"])

try:
   cidade= (Location.raw['address']['town'])
except:
   try:
      cidade= (Location.raw['address']['city'])
   except:
      try:
         cidade =(Location.raw['address']['state'])
      except:
         try:
            cidade= (Location.raw['address']['municipality'])
         except:
            cidade="Nao encontrado"

listacidades.append(cidade)
```

My Excel Table:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your test list?

Comment: Column Intens: 

13 , 122
12 , 78
43 , 12
63 , 16
40, -4

// List Result: Castile-La Mancha (only 1 item)

Comment: @Ferby is your code formatted properly here? I mean is the indentation correct?

Comment: yes @RitwikG .. it works.. the result is a list with only 1 item.. i Try manually (without the looping) and it works as well

Comment: @Ferby if the indentation is correct here then there is no wonder you are getting only 1 item. Because under for loop you only have `coord = str(row['Concatenado'])`. So at the end of the loop `coord` will be equal to last row only and you are executing remaining logic and `listacidades.append(cidade)` only exactly one time against the lase `coord`. You probably need to move that code inside for loop for your indented behavior